# pycharm builtin unresolved reference

Tags: python, pycharm, built-in

I'm using PyCharm and just trying out some simple stuff. When I try to use `raw_input()`, the editor is showing an unresolved reference error.

I'm not sure what the issue is. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: dmitry's response from this thread worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the language version set to Python 3; `raw_input` in Python 2 is just `input` in Python 3 (`input` in Python 2 is `eval(input())` in Python 3: [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)).

To select the Python version, see: [How to select Python version in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322424/how-to-select-python-version-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a similar issue. `@property` and `ValueError` were being shown as 'undefined'. I had mucked about with PyCharm's interpreter settings a bit beforehand, and I was able to fix it by using the File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and choosing the "Invalidate and Restart" command.

Comment: Getting this to work eludes me.  I've watched the task that rebuilds the index run, and then subsequently reparse my source and mark all the built in as unknown.  This is so frustrating, as I have been liking this IDE for cross platform use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same error message when I tried :

```
variable = print("Some Text")
```

The problem is double quotes, single quotes will solve the problem as follows :

```
variable = print('Some text')
```