# PyCharm cannot find library

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 5 to run a Python 2.7 (Anaconda) script in Ubuntu. My script imports a module with `import tensorflow`, but this causes the error `ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So, it seems that the library `libcudart.so.7.0` is needed by this module, but it cannot be found.

Now, I have seen that this library is on my machine in `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`. So, in PyCharm, I went to `Settings->Project Interpreters->Interpreter Paths`. This had a list of paths, such as `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/python2.7`. I then added to this list, the path mentioned above which contains the required library.

However, this did not fix the problem. I still get an error telling me that `libcudart.so.7.0` cannot be found. If I run my script from the shell though (`python myfile.py`), then it runs fine.

How can I tell PyCharm where to find this library?

---

I have noticed that if I have `print sys.path` in my script, the paths it prints out are entirely different to those in `Settings->Project Interpreters->Interpreter Paths`... should they be the same?

Comment: Is PyCharm running your script using the same `python` as your terminal? That would be the first look. Make sure the run configuration is using the correct interpreter. Run > Edit Configurations. Select your project, then under the Project Interpreter, make sure you have your anaconda python selected.

Comment: Yes -- I have Anaconda Python selected for my PyCharm project, and also the interpreter in my terminal...

Comment: I don't know then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu could help you with further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I came across this problem just recently using a remote debugger, however I believe it's still the same solution. I just added the following to the Environment Variables section in the Run/Debug Configuration options found in Run > Edit Configurations... dialog: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I found that calling predefined environment variables within this dialog didn't work. I needed to use the full path when defining these environment variables.

Comment: I found this solution worked best for me when installing TensorFlow in an Anaconda environment and using PyCharm as my IDE. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

The path to your cuda library seems strange to me.  I would expect it to be `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64` or `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib`.

Did you follow all of the [cuda installation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#axzz3ryQCVSOx) procedure?

If you type `env` on the command line, do you see a path to cuda in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

---

Update from comments below:

The issue is that PyCharm was invoked from the desktop, and wasn't getting the right environment variables.  Solution is to either:

- invoke from the command line,
- create a script to set environment and then invoke, and make a link to that script on the desktop,
- or set environment variables on the desktop item

Comment: Yes, I followed the official CUDA installation instructions. The directory at /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64` is actually a symbolic link to `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`. I'm not sure why that link was made, but I didn't do it manually. Typing in `env` gives me: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/CUDNN-7.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`. So the required directory is there (hence why my script works when running from the terminal), but it seems that PyCharm does not use this environment variable.

Comment: Just on a lark here, are you running pycharm from an icon on the desktop?  Have you tried invoking it from a shell that has all of the environment variables set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I was running PyCharm from an icon...if I try running it from a shell, then the script works! But I don't want to have to have to do that...! There must be a way for PyCharm to load these same environment variables...

Comment: Nice!  So you can write a shell script that sets the environment and invokes pycharm, and then put a link to that shell script on your desktop, or alternatively you can set the environment for an icon-invoked program using a method like this: http://askubuntu.com/a/144971/471356

Comment: It did solve the issue -- thanks -- although I am still assuming there is a solution to set the library paths within PyCharm. Surely this is a standard requirement...!

Answer (score 11):

While some of these answers are correct, and could work, I haven't seen what the OP specifically asked for, and that is where to set environments for the python console. This can be accomplished inside pycharm at:

File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Console > Python Console

In the options there, you'll find a place to define Environment Variables. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH there.
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This appears to have been similar to the solution I was searching for. It looks like the issue I was facing was that I was attempting to call the predefined Environment Variable $CUDA_HOME/lib from within PyCharms Configuration Setting dialog. When I changed to the full /usr/local/cuda/lib everything started to work.

Comment: Agreed, that this seems like the actual answer. Also setting CUDA_HOME to /usr/local/cuda is also a good idea in the environments section of pycharm.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `pycharm.desktop`, specify the environment variable in exec, like below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Pycharm
Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64 /home/cwh/software/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin/pycharm.sh
Icon=/home/cwh/software/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin/pycharm.png
Name[zh_CN]=Pycharm
```

so `pycharm` will find `cuda`

Comment: However, this approach does not apply to a remote debugger.

Comment: @HaoTan You can add LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your run configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Have you selected the right python interpreter in your project's settings?
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322460).

I had a similar issue and changing the interpreter solved it without having to create a new icon.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on `Community edition 2019.3`

To set globally for a project:

- Open `File/Settings/Project/Project Interpreter`
- click on the cog icon next to the interpreter
- choose show all
- click on the little folder with tree icon bottom right
- add the path to "Interpreter Paths"