# Pycharm can't change interpreter from python 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, anki

Im currently working on an open source Python project on Xubuntu Linux 3.19.0-51-generic x86_64 using Pycharm.
Even though I my project requires Python 3.4 or greater, the IDE seems to force the project to use Python 2.7. I've tried to change the interpreter from the Project Interpreter menu (see screenshot), and went so far as to remove the Python 2.7 entry from the Project Interpreter menu..All to no avail. I have attached a screenshot of Project Interpreter menu and here is the first line of my debugger session to illustrate the problem:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/bluejay/pycharm/pycharm-community-2016.2.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --cmd-line --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 45167 --file /root/PycharmProjects/anki/runanki
```

[image: Project Interpreter Menu]

Any help is vastly appreciated!

Comment: Try use virtualenv to work with several version of python

Comment: I already have both versions installed to my OS, what do you mean?

Comment: try whit this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html or this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to setup different interpreter in run/debug configuration in the same manner as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524553/5485944).

Main Menu -> Run -> Edit Configurations...

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, saved me some hair pulling. The settings for the project interpreter and the specific run configurations (such as 'Python Interpreter') within a specific project are defaulted differently.