# I have two python 3 versions on my Mac. How do I use the new version and/remove the old one?

Tags: python

I have Python 3.6.5 and Python 3.7.4 installed.

```
python --version
```

gives me 3.6, while

```
python3 --version
```

gives me 3.7. Running code in PyCharm indicates that it is still using 3.6. How do I update it to start using 3.7, and/or remove 3.6?

I've looked around SO and other forums, but so far nothing seemed to be relevant to this specific issue.

Comment: When you say remove, do you want to uninstall these python version?

Comment: @YacineMahdid I'm not sure if I need to uninstall it. I just want to stop using 3.6 and work with 3.7 if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your other python versions and want PyCharm to run your code in the 3.7 version you can simply go into your PyCharm preference and set the project interpreter to 3.7.

Here is a [stack overflow question showing you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322424/how-to-select-python-version-in-pycharm)

If you don't see the python interpreter there you can add it manually before setting it in the preferences. Here is a [doc page that might help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but wasn't sure if it required removal of 3.6. Works like a charm. Thanks!