# Can't import numpy even after I installed it?

Tags: python, numpy, module

I have to import numpy for a project in python, and I was told to simply install it in the CMD prompt, (pip install numpy). It says it is installed, but when I try to import it in python, it says: no module named 'numpy'. What did I do wrong or how do I fix this?

Comment: Try install with pip3 or running just with python Script.py

Comment: can you explain in more detail, I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: when you use pip install package, you can "use" the package executing python your_script.py and the same is for pip3 and python3

Comment: okay thanks will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python version that is lower than 3 the method you tried should work so I am assuming you have a python version of 3.x.

For that you have to use

```
pip3 install numpy
```

As pip is for version lower than python 3 but pip3 is the one for python3.

**EDIT**

Since you said that it works in command prompt, so I believe that the pycharm is not using python3...?

If that’s the case try [visiting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322424/how-to-select-python-version-in-pycharm) and set the appropriate version.

Hope it helps

Comment: idk if this helps, but it all works in the CMD prompt, but not in pycharm

Comment: i found this site and it works now (https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/pycharm#:~:text=To%20install%20NumPy%20on%20PyCharm,time%20that%20it%20executed%20successfully.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to ensure you are using the python and pip in the same bin and the installation of numpy is also in the same bin, you can try:

```
$ python -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: it still tells me no module named numpy when i try to import it

Comment: idk if this helps, but it all works in the CMD prompt, but not in pycharm

Comment: Read about you have resolved the issue from the pycharm settings. Congrats!