# Python Modules error with Pycharm, Homebrew and Pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have Python 3.9.5 installed via Homebrew, but when downloading modules via pip3, the modules are visible in the 'pip3 list' but not in my interpreter modules in PyCharm. What have I done wrong?

PyCharm Interpreter:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

Pip3 modules location:
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip

Comment: You have 2 versions of Python 3.9 on your machine. One in /Library, and one in Homebrew. You have to configure PyCharm to use/select the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select Python version in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322424/how-to-select-python-version-in-pycharm)

Comment: @GinoMempin I removed other interpreters and set it as the following:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3.9
I can now see when modules are installed/uninstalled from the module library.
Will this cause issues?

Comment: Try it and see :) Having multiple python versions is "normal". You just have to get used to selecting the right one. I recommend learning how to create virtual environments, preferrably 1 virtual env for each Python project you are working on. Instead of using system-wide site-packages. Then in PyCharm, for every project, you just select the appropriate virtual env.